# Vuetify.js: how to change the color of the step's text in a v-stepper component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In the [v-stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) VuetifyJS component, I know how to change the color of the steps themselves by simply invoking the `color` prop, but how to change the text of that step?

I mean how to change the color of *Name of step 1* text below:

```
 <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1" color="red">Name of step 1</v-stepper-step>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/VEpdmL?&editors=101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically if you wanted to go the Vuetify.js way, you could use the `red--text` class in your span like so:

```
<span class="red--text">Name of Step 1</span>
```

Or, if you're feeling reckless and irresponsible you could just override the CSS for `.v-stepper__label`.

```
.v-stepper__label {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that notation is a Vuetify way of doing things, thank you

Comment: The problem with override is that it's applied to global scope. Gotta add class name to component first eg: `.my-stepper .v-stepper__label {`

Answer (score 0):

I just came back to this issue and found a simple solution:

I just wrapped `<span style="color:red">Name of Step 1</span>`

But if you have a Vuetify.js way of doing this, please let me know.